# margin below of the footer differs about 1cm in dinbrief than in moderncv

Tags: fancyhdr, moderncv, dinbrief

I simply want my moderncv document have the same foot margin as my dinbrief document. However, when i print both and measure the gap between the footer and the end of the paper, the gap differs in about 1 cm. I don't mean the gap right of left of the footer, rather the one below.

How can I fix this?

## moderncv

I have this code, using the `moderncv` class:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\firstname{Max}
\familyname{Mustermann}


\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[c]{%
  \textcolor{color2}{
    \centering%
      test }}%

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
test
\end{document}
```

## dinbrief

Then i have this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{dinbrief}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\address{}

\nobackaddressrule
\nowindowtics
\nowindowrules
\addresshigh

\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}% dark grey

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[c]{%
  \textcolor{color2}{%
    \centering%
      test }}%end fancyfoot

\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
\subject{}
\opening{}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, i still don't know what caused that issue, but adding `\space{1cm}` results acutally in the desired effect. I just didn't saw that solution the first time.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{dinbrief}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\address{}

\nobackaddressrule
\nowindowtics
\nowindowrules
\addresshigh

\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}% dark grey

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[c]{%
  \vspace{1cm}%<<<<<<<<
  \textcolor{color2}{%
    \centering%
      test }}%end fancyfoot

\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
\subject{}
\opening{}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```